# How to save an SSH key passphrase in gnome-keyring?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent, gnome-keyring

I want to save an SSH key passphrase in gnome-keyring and then use it automatically when I need it.

How to do this?

Answer (score 16):

If `gnome-keyring-daemon` is already running, you can use `ssh-add` to add your key to the service:

```
ssh-add /path/to/private/key
```

For example:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 9):

To save the passphrase, use `seahorse-ssh-askpass` from package `seahorse`:

```
cd $HOME/.ssh
/usr/lib/seahorse/seahorse-ssh-askpass my_key
```

Make sure that the public key is the filename of the private key plus `.pub`, in the example `my_key.pub`

To automatically use the key afterwards, see ["Gnome Keyring dialog and SSH"](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME_Keyring#Gnome_Keyring_dialog_and_SSH) and at first use, check "Automatically unlock this key whenever I'm logged in".

Comment: I used this command successfully with Ubuntu 10.04, it seems like it was not even required in Ubuntu 12.04, but with Ubuntu 14.04 I can't seem to be able to store my ssh key password.   
`seahorse-ssh-askpass` just prints the password I enter to stdout!!!

Comment: @asoundmove: I had the same experience on 16.04. You can use the seahorse prompt utility via `ssh-add`, however: `SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/lib/seahorse/seahorse-ssh-askpass ssh-add /path/to/private/key </dev/null`. Redirecting standard input is required to force the use of `SSH_ASKPASS` (graphical prompt).

Comment: `seahorse-ssh-askpass` is just `ssh-askpass` in my system. [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring#SSH_keys)

Comment: @zackse - In Ubuntu (19.10 at the moment) it is `/usr/libexec/seahorse/ssh-askpass`, but… yes, it adds the key to the agent and uses graphical prompt but this doesn't solve the problem. Next time I have to add the key again and enter the passphrase again…

Comment: The important part for me was to have the public and private key pair in the same place

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **gnome-keyring-daemon** but a **ssh-agent** that is not managed by the keyring, you can still manually store the passphrase in the keyring and use **secret-tool** (via `apt install libsecret-tools`) and an **expect** script (via `apt install expect`) when adding the key to your agent:

```bsh
# Save passphrase to keyring via same format used by seahorse-ssh-askpass
# only required if entry does not already exist in the keyring
secret-tool store --label="Unlock password for: id_ed25519" unique "ssh-store:/home/$USER/.ssh/id_ed25519"

# Load key into ssh agent
FILE="/home/$USER/.ssh/id_ed25519"
PASS=$(secret-tool lookup unique ssh-store:$FILE)
/usr/bin/expect <(echo "
spawn ssh-add $FILE
expect \"Enter passphrase for $FILE\"
send -- \"$PASS\n\"
expect eof")

# Results should look like:
Enter passphrase for /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519: 
Identity added: /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 (username@example.com)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your private (e.g. `mykey`) and public (e.g. `mykey.pub`) key are stored in the `~/.ssh` directory. Then it will be loaded automatically.

From Gnome Keyring docs (Automatically loading SSH Keys):

> The SSH agent automatically loads files in ~/.ssh which have corresponding *.pub paired files. Additional SSH keys can be manually loaded and managed via the ssh-add command.