# How to set-up gnome keyring for passwordless ssh/sshfs using the keyring to unlock the key with the stored passphrase?

Tags: ssh, login, sshfs, gnome-keyring

I have an ssh key in my gnome keyring, protected by a password.
I have the "Unlock password" for that key saved in my login keyring.

If I unlock my login keyring, I can ssh without password entry.
If my keyring is locked, the first time I ssh, it will prompt me for the ssh key password, then keeps it for the rest of the session.

However what I am trying to achieve, and what I perceive as the purpose of the login keyring, when I login using my fingerprint (which automatically enters my password, also note that my keyring password is the same as the login password), is that I should be able to use my ssh key (for `sshfs`) without having to type any password since it is held in my login keyring.

Is the keyring only unlocked for the execution of one particular start-up script - which I have not been able to identify (`.profile` is not it, I tried, it prompts for passwords when I try to ssh or mount `sshfs`)?

So my question is how I may be able to gain access to ssh/sshfs by using the stored password in my login keyring (at login).

Or in other words: is it possible to set up gnome keyring for passwordless ssh/sshfs, using the keyring to unlock the ssh key with the stored passphrase?

I have checked this, but it does not answer my request "[How to save an SSH key passphrase in gnome-keyring?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168062/how-to-save-an-ssh-key-passphrase-in-gnome-keyring?rq=1)"

Note: I am on Ubuntu 10.04 (I know I should upgrade, that's scheduled for later)

EDIT: I routinely login with my fingerprint, I tried a password login instead, as a result the login keyring unlocks and therefore ssh/sshfs work without me entering any password beyond the login.
So now the question is how to unlock the keyring with fingerprint authentication.

ANSWER: https://askubuntu.com/questions/39217/unlock-keyring-with-fingerprint-reader-on-login/238055#238055
In short, no the keyring cannot be unlocked with fingerprint authentication.
If I want it unlocked, I need to use my login password.

Question closed.

Comment: In ubuntu you can see the gnome-keyring starting from `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop`. It stores only keys, not the passphrases nor any passwords.

Comment: Maybe it's me conflating gnome-keyring and seahorse, but using seahorse I certainly have passwords in there. There is something I don't get.

Comment: Seahorse is just a GUI to communicate with the `gnome-keyring` daemon afaik. The passwords are stored there for browsers, but can't be used for SSH passwords, if it is your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER: https://askubuntu.com/questions/39217/unlock-keyring-with-fingerprint-reader-on-login/238055#238055 In short, no the keyring cannot be unlocked with fingerprint authentication. If I want it unlocked, I need to use my login password.

Answer (score 0):

> how I may be able to gain access to ssh/sshfs by using the stored password in my login keyring (at login).

No, you can't. SSH communicates with the gnome-keyring using `ssh-agent` protocol and it supports only private key operations, not passing passwords.

Comment: Why then, when I unlock the keyring, ssh logs me in without password entry?

Comment: you mean passphrase?

Comment: Yes, but seahorse calls it the "unlock password", so I'm using their terminology. But yes I mean the passphrase for my key.

Comment: Normal ssh-agent does not store passphrases for keys, but gnome-keyring probably does. Can you once more restate the question? It is still not clear what you mean.

Comment: Yes, is it possible to set up gnome keyring for passwordless ssh/sshfs, using the keyring to unlock the ssh key with the stored passphrase?

Comment: I don't think so. If you need to automate something, you better use unencrypted private keys (with possible permission limitation on the serve side).

Comment: But again, why then, when I unlock the keyring, ssh logs me in without password entry (I take it that it uses the stored passphrase)?